# Property 'window' not found on object of type 'BSViewController *'

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to make a UIButton display an image and am getting the Title error.

Also I would like to know why `()` is needed on `BSViewController ()` as it was created by XCode?

```
//
//  BSViewController.m

#import "BSViewController.h"

@interface BSViewController ()    // Why the "()"?
@end

@implementation BSViewController


- (IBAction) chooseImage:(id) sender{


    UIImageView* testCard = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ipad 7D.JPG"]]; 
//Property 'window' not found on object of type 'BSViewController *'
    self.window.rootViewController = testCard;
    [self.window.rootViewController addSubview: testCard];
    testCard.center = self.window.rootViewController.center;

     NSLog(@"chooseImage");

}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end



//
//  BSViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class BSViewController;
@interface BSViewController : UIViewController
<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>{
    IBOutlet UIButton* chooseImage;
}


- (IBAction) chooseImage:(id) sender;

@end
```

Comment: When I enter this `@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWindow *window;` I get the error `Incompatible pointer types assigning to UIViewController * from UIImageView* __strong `.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This line:

```
    self.window.rootViewController = testCard;
```

Is an attempt to assign an imageView object pointer to an existing viewController object pointer. You should have got a compiler warning about that. Then on the next line you effectively try to add it to itself as a subview, that probably kicks up a warning as well.

The () indicate a *category extension* to a class. It's an extension to your public interface which allows you to declare entities that should be private to the class. You should put most of your interface here, just keep things in your .h @interface that need to be public.

Your BSViewController class does not have a property called `window` so you cannot refer to it as `self.window`. But under normal  circumstances you should be able to get a reference to your window like this:

```
    UIWindow* window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    [window.rootViewController.view addSubview: testCard];
```

However, if you just want to put testCard into your instance of BSViewController you don't need to do that. You just need a reference to your current instance's view:

```
    [self.view addSubview:testCard];
```

Comment: It may seem that I want to know "Why I get this result" but I also need to know how to fix it, please.

Comment: first of all delete that line I mentioned... then - are you intending to add the image as a subview of your BSViewController instance, or of another controller? What is the relationship between the controllers?

Comment: I want the image to be in the same viewController for now. Eventually I want to use the UIImagePickerController to take pictures of playing cards so that I can recognize each of the 52 cards.